# How to promote my own app in my other app using Admob?

Tags: android, admob

I have two live apps and like to promote them through each other. I am using Admob for showing ads. After some search I came to know that I can use admob campaign for this purpose.

I have some Queries regarding this

1. Did I have to pay google anything to promote my own app in my other app?
2. It's say my ad will only show when I will not get any live ad (ad backfill). So is there any way that after every certain live ads, My ad show? (like after every 10 live ads, my own ad show)

Comment: Visit here. https://ads.google.com/home/campaigns/app-ads/

Comment: I end up doing my own. You can use firebase and firestorage to put your own advertising content. Then in your apps, have a routine who choose between your own app advertising or admob. Then don't don't have to rely on admob for that. If you switch for another ad support, your own app advertising is still working without changing anything.

Comment: Thank You, Now I got some idea about these problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of AdMob campaigns.

1. House ad campaigns
2. Direct sold campaigns

In your case your House ad campaigns. They are completely free.

Mediated ads (recommended for backfill)
Your ads compete in the mediation chain using an eCPM that can be optimized for backfill. You can choose how your ads will be ordered in the mediation chain using either:

Google optimized for backfill: Use your house ads as backfill when paid ads would have negligible value.
Manual eCPM: The eCPM value you set during campaign creation is used to place the campaign in competition against other CPM-based ad sources, including the AdMob Network, campaigns that use eCPM floors, and third-party ad networks. If your paid ads are below this eCPM value, your campaign will serve instead of your paid network ads.
Note: Though the manual eCPM is shown as a monetary value, mediated house ads are always free.

Mediated ads campaigns aren’t required to have a set end date, though you can set one if desired.

[About AdMob campaigns](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9152820)

[Create a new campaign](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6231370?hl=en)

Thanks